# Selenium and Salesforce Automation Click a specific account from my accounts page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, salesforce

I'm trying to create an automation script using salesforce and selenium to record a call.  I have been able to get my script to load the website, sign in, and navigate to the "my accounts" page. On that page it has a table of all accounts.  I am trying to click a specific account, but I am unable to get Selenium to find the element.  Here is what each element in the table looks like:

```
<tr class="dataRow even" onmouseover="if (typeof(hiOn) != 'undefined')  {hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (typeof(hiOff) != 'undefined'){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (typeof(hiOn) != 'undefined'){hiOn(this);}" onmouseout="if (typeof(hiOff) != 'undefined'){hiOff(this);}">
<td>
<input id="001U000000nyG6oIAE" type="checkbox" onchange="com.vod309.myaccounts.addOrRemoveAcct(this)">
<input id="isPerson" type="hidden" value="false">
</td>
<td class="dataCell">
<a target="_top" href="https://na12.salesforce.com/001U000000nyG6oIAE">CAP AREA SPCH CENTER</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Could anyone help me to get my script to correctly click the link to go to "CAP AREA SPCH CENTER"?

I have already tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("CAP AREA SPCH CENTER")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[55]/td[2]/a").click();
```

And many others, but for some reason, it does not correctly find the link.  I think it may be because the link is in the table?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `it does not correctly find the link`??is there any exception??

Comment: It gives me the exception, "no such element".  Even though as you can see in the part I posted above, there is an element with "CAP AREA SPCH CENTER" in it

Comment: Check your element may it is inside any frame or Iframe...if it is need to switch that frame first as :- `driver.switchTo().frame("frame name or id");`..

Comment: What if it's in an iframe and not a frame?  is it just

Comment: driver.switchTo().iframe("frame name or id");

Comment: Yes it works for both frame and Iframe..do this before finding element..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement WebDriverWait to wait until element visible and enable to click as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("CAP AREA SPCH CENTER"))).click();
```

Or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'CAP AREA SPCH CENTER')]"))).click();
```

**Edited** :- you need to switch Iframe first then go to find element as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("itarget");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("CAP AREA SPCH CENTER"))).click();
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately neither of these work, I think the issue is something with the salesforce site

Comment: @PhillipPowell what do you mean these are not work..is there any exception??? And make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe??

Comment: It still says "Element not found"  But you are correct, I found out the entire main section of the page is in this frame:

Comment: <iframe id="itarget" width="100%" height="6500px" frameborder="0" title="Content" src="/servlet/servlet.Integration?lid=01NU0000000J7ys&enc=UTF-8&ic=1&linkToken=VmpFPSxNakF4Tmkwd055MHlOMVF4TmpveE9Ub3hNeTQxTVRkYSxJSEVBOUUxRmVxYTBLbEhfZ3laOEJxLFlXWmtNR0po" scrolling="auto" name="itarget">

Comment: Thank you so much, you were right, the element was inside of an iframe, once I used driver.switchTo to change to the correct iframe, the element was found.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @PhillipPowell yeah..you welcome..glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `find_element_by_link_text`?

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("CAP AREA SPCH CENTER") 
elem.click()
```

Comment: isn't that the same as driver.findElement(By.linkText("CAP AREA SPCH CENTER")).click();?  I'm new to selenium so I don't know for sure